# is my code okay to execute "if a list has a certain word, remove the elements coming after that?"

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to write a code to remove all the words coming after a certain word from a set of words as below.
I tested out but since I'm quite new to python I'm not sure if this code might cause a problem.

Can anyone review this code and point any possible risk from using this code?

```
def to_lowercase(target):
    lowerlist=[x.lower() for x in target];
    for i in range(len(target)):
        target[i]=lowerlist[i]

def remove_equipment(targetlist):
    wordtarget=''
    for x in targetlist:
        if x in targetword:
            index =targetlist.index(x)
            del targetlist[index:]

targetword=['equipment:','accompaniments:','garnish:']

to_lowercase(testlist);

remove_equipment(testlist);
```

I tested with test list below.

```
testlist= ['brioche','sandwich','bread,','shrimp,','peeled,','tail','fan','attached,','butter','dill','shallot','Equipment:','cups']
```

So far, I haven't seen any error.

Comment: For starters, `to_lowercase()` isn't returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably works, but some suggestions:

1. Store your intended results in a separate list instead of changing (mutating) the original `testlist`. This can be useful if you need to compare the lists before and after your changes.
2. Convention is to use underscores to separate words in variable names: `test_list` instead of `testlist`
3. Avoid looping through `test_list` multiple times. Currently, `to_lowercase` loops once, `remove_equipment` once, and `targetlist.index(x)` will also loop. See below for a simplified approach:

```
test_list = ['brioche','sandwich', 'bread,','shrimp,','peeled,','tail','fan','attached,','butter','dill','shallot','Equipment:','cups']
target_word = ['equipment:','accompaniments:','garnish:']

# to store results
res = []

for word in test_list:
    # assumes you want only lowercase results
    word = word.lower()

    # add word to result list.
    # assumes that you want to keep words up to and including the target word.
    # e.g. [..., 'garnish:']
    res.append(word)
    
    if word in target_word:
        # break to end the for-loop since you don't want anything beyond this word
        break

print(res)
# prints ['brioche', 'sandwich', 'bread,', 'shrimp,', 'peeled,', 'tail', 'fan', 'attached,', 'butter', 'dill', 'shallot', 'equipment:']
```

Comment: This will not work if more than 1 word match.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by more than 1 word match here, could you explain that pls?

Comment: Try using  `target_word = ['equipment:','brioche','garnish:']` - https://trinket.io/python3/1a9eb132ad

Comment: I the OP only needs to match one word, I don't see the point of `targetword` being a `list` instead of a `string`, go figure...

Comment: From the link you sent, the result shows just `['brioche']` when using the `target_word` you shared above. Based on the question ('remove all the words coming after a certain word from a set of words'), it seems to be the required behaviour. As long as a word matches any of the 3 words in `target_word`, remove everything after that

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is good, it could be simplified a little bit.

```
def to_lowercase(target):
    return [x.lower() for x in target]

def remove_equipment(targetlist):
    last_index = len(targetlist)
    for i, x in enumerate(targetlist):
        if x in targetword:
            last_index = i + 1
            break
    return targetlist[:last_index]

testlist= ['brioche','sandwich','bread,','shrimp,','peeled,','tail','fan','attached,','butter','dill','shallot','Equipment:','cups']

targetword = ['equipment:','accompaniments:','garnish:']

testlist = to_lowercase(testlist)

testlist = remove_equipment(testlist)

print(testlist)
##output
['brioche', 'sandwich', 'bread,', 'shrimp,', 'peeled,', 'tail', 'fan', 'attached,', 'butter', 'dill', 'shallot', 'equipment:']
```

Remember to break the loop once your condition was satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
targetword=['equipment:','accompaniments:','garnish:']
testlist= [i.lower() for i in ['brioche','sandwich','bread,','shrimp,','peeled,','tail','fan','attached,','butter','dill','shallot','Equipment:','cups']]

for w in targetword:
  if w in testlist:
    try:
      del testlist[testlist.index(w) + 1]
    except:
      print("Index out of bounds")

print(testlist)
# ['brioche', 'sandwich', 'bread,', 'shrimp,', 'peeled,', 'tail', 'fan', 'attached,', 'butter', 'dill', 'shallot', 'Equipment:']
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/5d660d9744)